# Correct Rails way of validating a floating number (inside range)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Using Rails v5.0.0.1, and given a form:

```
<%= form_for(map, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

  <%# several inputs ... %>

  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :longitude, t("label.longitude") %>
      <%= f.number_field :longitude,
          :class => "form-control",
          :value => "0.000000",
          :step => "0.000001",
          :min => "-180.000000",
          :max => "180.000000"
      %>
  </div>

  <%# several inputs ... %>

  <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
</form>
```

The form submits, the controller kicks in, and the "magic" of rails happens.

Until the validation part.

At the model, I've attempted several different validators, from a simple `validate` block, to a `validates_numericality_of`.

As so:

```
validate do
    errors.add(:longitude, 'bum') unless (-180.0..180.0).include?(longitude)
end
```

And even:

```
validates_numericality_of :longitude,
    :greather_than_or_equal_to => -180.0,
    :less_than_or_equal_to => 180.0
```

However, every value that I try ( 0, 0.000000, 180 ) says it's out of bounds.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Could you do something like `validates_inclusion_of :longitude, :in => -180..180` ?

Comment: Same error ;\\\

Comment: Can I ask, why are you using `<%` for your number field? Shouldnt you be printing it and using `<%=`

Comment: @luka that was a typo when creating the snippet :P